# How to get all roles from RoleHierarchyImpl

Tags: spring-security

I have a hierarchy of roles configured and working:

```
<beans:bean id="roleHierarchy"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <beans:property name="hierarchy">
        <beans:value>
            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_PRIVILEGED
            ROLE_PRIVILEGED > ROLE_USER
            ROLE_USER > ROLE_ANONYMOUS
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

For user roles setting I need to access which roles I have defined. How can I achieve it? Probably with `roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities` but I dont know, what to give it as parameter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

As I understand, you want to get all the reachable granted authorities from a given granted authority. If this is the case, below is the workaround solution:

- First get the `RoleHierarchyImpl` instance either from Spring `ApplicationContext`

  ```
   ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
          "--path--");
   BeanFactory factory = context;
   RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = (RoleHierarchyImpl) factory.getBean("roleHierarchy");`
  ```

or create a new instance and load the Hierarchy as like below;

```
     RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
     roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(properties.getProperty("security.roleHierarchy"));
```

- Now you can use `roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities` and `AuthorityUtils` to get all the reachable granted authorities:

  ```
   Collection<GrantedAuthority> ga = roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities(AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(new String[]{"ROLE_ADMIN"}));
  ```